# viewing/Downloading a file from a webview

Tags: cocoa

Guyss I have a webview which basically contains an attachment. So my question is that how can I view/download that particular file may be .pdf/.docx/.xls etc ffrom that web view.

Comment: You can't make Xcode download your files. Did you mean by accident to do it with your application?

Comment: Actually i want my app to view some files like .pdf,.doc etc which would be basically present in a web view(i mean a link to that file present on the server)...So my question is how can i view those files ??